# how to fix the json setting in vscode for python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

I have not used vscode for a while, and when i opened it last night. It won't let me change any setting because the error in the json setting. I tried to fix it but i failed.

[image]

[image]

Thank you for some people helping me to fix the first part of the code. But i still have the error for the second part. Tried to remove and add the {}, but it does not help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you don't have valid json.

delete the code runner line or add a value to it with a comma at the end

something got borked up on your settings file

valid json is like this

```json
{
"key": value,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like te json is not well formatted. For every array you should have key:value, but on your screenshot seems like you wrote key:key:value.

Answer (score 0):

In the setting file "`settings.json`", we need to pay attention to: 1. Please use "`,`" to separate the settings; 2. As people say, we need to write the settings completely. (For settings that are not used, we can comment them out.)

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: @Gracetam -Does my answer solve this problem for you? If so, please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer to help others who have the same problem.